# How do you catch a specific type of exception without passing the results to the caller in F#?

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I am trying to capture a specific exception to acquire the underlying message for logging but I don't want the exception passed back to the calling method. I know how to do this in C#, F#? meh.

Here is the code that works w/o targeting a specific exception type. I simply log that a problem occurred within the method

```
        match remoteApiResponse.StatusCode with
        | HttpStatusCode.OK ->
            let! resp = remoteApiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
            try
                let IsSuccess = JObject.Parse(resp).["IsSuccess"].ToString().Trim().ToLower()
                match IsSuccess with
                | "true" -> ()
                | "false" -> remoteApiResponse.StatusCode <- HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
                | _ -> ()
            with 
            | _ ->  logger.LogError("Error Occurred during IsSuccess flag validation.") 
        | _ -> ()
```

In the following code I have targeted to evaluate a NullReferenceException type but it could be any type of error really

```
    match remoteApiResponse.StatusCode with
        | HttpStatusCode.OK ->
            let! resp = remoteApiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
            try
                let IsSuccess = JObject.Parse(resp).["IsSuccess"].ToString().Trim().ToLower()
                match IsSuccess with
                | "true" -> ()
                | "false" -> remoteApiResponse.StatusCode <- HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
                | _ -> ()
            with 
            | :? NullReferenceException as ne -> logger.LogError("Error Occurred during IsSuccess flag validation." + ne.Message) 
        | _ -> ()
```

The problem I'm seeing is when I specify an Exception type the exception gets passed by up the chain to the calling method. The first method works as is but it isn't collecting very useful information.

The 2nd method would be the way to go to capture more specifics of the error but it always carries the exception up the chain.

How can my 2nd version of the code be minimally modified (if possible) to prevent the error from being passed back to the caller?
Pretty sure there is an easy way to fix this issue but I'm not 100% how in F#

Comment: What do you want to happen with other types of exceptions? Other than `NullReferenceException`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like in C#, you can have several patterns in the `with` block. They will be matched in order. Use the first one to catch the exception you'd like to log, then use a catch-all pattern to swallow all other exceptions:

```
try
  ...
with
| ?: NullReferenceException as ne -> logger.LogError ...
| _ -> ()
```

---

**EDIT** in response to comments.

> If ?: is the catch what is _ -> () and why is it needed?

Both `:?` and `_ ->` are "the catch".

In F#, just like in C#, one can have multiple `catch` blocks - several for different types of exceptions and, optionally, one catch-all block, for all exception types not explicitly mentioned in other blocks.

For example, in C#:

```
try { throw ... }
catch (NullReferenceException e) { Console.WriteLine("Null"); }
catch (NotImplementedException e) { Console.WriteLine("Not impl"); }
catch (InvalidOperationException e) { Console.WriteLine("Invalid op"); }
catch { Console.WriteLine("No idea what happened"); }
```

Equivalent code in F#:

```
try
  ...
with
| ?: NullReferenceException as e -> printfn "Null"
| ?: NotImplementedException as e -> printfn "Not impl"
| ?: InvalidOperationException as e -> printfn "Invalid op"
| _ -> printfn "No idea what happened"
```

The F# version does have a bit more flexibility - e.g. you can use `when` guards or deeply pattern-match on [F#-defined exception types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/exception-handling/exception-types). But the idea is the same: multiple catchers, tested in succession until one matches.

Another thing to note is that the syntax `:?` is not special to exception handling. It's syntax for pattern-matching on class hierarchy. For example, you can use it in a regular function:

```
let isString (o: obj) = 
  match o with 
  | :? string -> true
  | _ -> false
```

---

> I would think that rather somewhat of stating a "final" ending action

The words "rather" and "somewhat" belong to natural languages. Programming language constructs, on the other hand, have very specific, strictly defined meanings, which may or may not match your intuition at any given moment.

In particular, the `finally` block in C#/F# is not the same as "catching all other exceptions". While exception catchers execute only when an exception has happened, the `finally` block executes **regardless** of whether an exception has happened.

When no exception happens, the `finally` block executes after `try` as normal. When an exception does happen, the `finally` block executes *before* the exception is raised, and, crucially, the exception flight continues after the `finally` block is done executing. Just to drive this home, one more time: the `finally` block **does not stop the exception**.

The idea of the `finally` block is to allow you to clean up resources and be sure that the cleanup happens whether or not an exception occurs.

In C#:

```
try { Console.WriteLine("Working"); }
finally { Console.WriteLine("Done"); }
```

In F#:

```
try
  printfn "Working"
finally
  printfn "Done"
```

Another thing to note is that, unlike C#, F# does not allow to have both `with` and `finally` in the same block for complicated reasons. So if you need both, you have to nest them inside each other.

In C#:

```
try { Console.WriteLine("Working"); }
catch (NullReferenceException e) { Console.WriteLine("Null"); }
finally { Console.WriteLine("Cleanup"); }
```

In F#:

```
try
  try
    printfn "Working"
  with :? NullReferenceException ->
    printfn "Null"
finally
  printfn "Done"
```

---

For more information, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/exception-handling/the-try-finally-expression).

Comment: Thanks, I think the last line of your answer is what I needed to resolve the issue. Adding that line prevented the error from traveling back upstream. I guess this is similar to C# try-catch-finally but the manner the exception gets handles seems to be slightly different in F# b/c in C# I could omit the finally block and it would be adequate to not allow the exception to continue further. But in F#, seems the results are different if that last line you added is missing... lesson learned.

Comment: There is no `finally` block in this F# code

Comment: I don't get it then. If ?: is the catch what is _ -> () and why is it needed? If it is telling F# to ignore every other exception I would think that rather somewhat of stating a "final" ending action.

Comment: I amended the answer.